# ListCell not show on ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

At this time I learned how to make a program with javafx fxml application. I  find out how to display listcell on listview. I use the code below. But from the code, it is not able to display listcell on the listview. When I run the program just show listview and listcell does not appear.
please help me.

**Main.java**

```js
public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

**Main.fxml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="376.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Student.java**

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package belajarlistview;

/**
 *
 * @author kuupie
 */
public class Student {
    
    private static int studentIdAct = 0;
    private int studentId;
    private String name;
    private GENDER gender;

    enum GENDER {
        MALE,
        FEMALE
    }

    public Student(String name, GENDER gender) {
        studentId = studentIdAct++;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GENDER getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(GENDER gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

**ListCell.fxml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane fx:id="listCellDetail" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="421.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label1" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Label">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="label2" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="fxIconGender" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeLineJoin="ROUND" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**StudentListViewCell.java**

```js
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Johannes on 23.05.16.
 *
 */

public class StudentListViewCell extends ListCell<Student> {

    @FXML
    private Label label1;

    @FXML
    private Label label2;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView fxIconGender;

    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    private FXMLLoader mLLoader;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Student student, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(student, empty);
        
                mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListCell.fxml"));
                mLLoader.setController(this);

                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            label1.setText(String.valueOf(student.getStudentId()));
            label2.setText(student.getName());

            if(student.getGender().equals(Student.GENDER.MALE)) {
                fxIconGender.setIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.MARS);
            } else if(student.getGender().equals(Student.GENDER.FEMALE)) {
                fxIconGender.setIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.VENUS);
            } else {
                fxIconGender.setIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.GENDERLESS);
            }

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(gridPane);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package belajarlistview;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Student> listView;

    private final ObservableList<Student> studentObservableList;

    public Controller()  {

        studentObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        //add some Students
        studentObservableList.addAll(
                new Student("John Doe", Student.GENDER.MALE),
                new Student("Jane Doe", Student.GENDER.FEMALE),
                new Student("Donte Dunigan", Student.GENDER.MALE),
                new Student("Gavin Genna", Student.GENDER.MALE),
                new Student("Darin Dear", Student.GENDER.MALE),
                new Student("Pura Petty", Student.GENDER.FEMALE),
                new Student("Herma Hines", Student.GENDER.FEMALE)
        );


    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        listView.setItems(studentObservableList);
        listView.setCellFactory(studentListView -> new StudentListViewCell());

    }

}
```

I tried alot of code to solve it, by adding
this code `setGraphic(student == null ? null : gridPane);` on `StudentListViewCell.java` and
adding
this code `fx:controller="belajarlistview.Controller"` on `Main.fxml`

But i have got some error like this :
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBwBP.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q72c4.png)

please help me

Comment: You're missing the `fx:controller="belajarlistview.Controller"` attribute in the root element of `Main.fxml`; at least that's what I think you're trying to achieve

Comment: Furthermore I do not recommend reloading the `GridPane` in every call of `updateItem`, since these calls could happen frequently during scrolling leading to laggy scrolling. It's better to load this just once from the cell constructor and do `setGraphic(student == null ? null : gridPane);`. Also `updateItem` may be called for empty cells which results in `student` being `null` resulting in NPEs in your code. PS: Note that according to the java naming conventions only `static final` fields are all uppercase. Type names should use CamelCase (`GENDER` should be called `Gender`).

Answer (score 0):

Okay
I got the problem. The main problem on this code `mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListCell.fxml"));` just change this one `("/fxml/ListCell.fxml")` to `("ListCell.fxml")` the program runs well. Thanks so much @fabian